# How to force "is not None" test

Tags: python

I have an API in Python which can return an object, or `None` if no object is found. I want to avoid run-time exceptions/crashes, etc., hence I want to force the users of my API, to do an `is not None` test.

For example:

```
x = getObject(...)
if x is not None:
   print x.getName()  #should be o.k.


y = getObject(...)
print y.getName() # print an error to the log
```

How can I achieve that?

In comparable code in C++, I can add a flag that will be checked when I call the `getName()`; the flag is set only upon comparing the object to `NULL`.

In Python, however, I am unable to overload the `is` operator. Are there any other ways I can achieve that functionality in Python?

Comment: Generally, in Python, the answer to "how do I force my users to..." is "you can't; a sufficiently determined user can foil your every attempt"

Comment: `In a comparable code in c++, I can add a flag that will be checked when I call the getName(), the flag is set only upon comparing the object to NULL` - How? Can you show a code sample? If the object itself is NULL, how can you call `getName` on it?

Comment: Avoid returning `None` in favor to [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: Why not make your API raise an error rather than returning `None`? The user will then be forced to either handle the error or face the consequences.

Comment: To avoid crashes, check the user isn't passing `None` to your API. Any other crashes are their responsibility, not yours.

Comment: I don't understand. Just use a `try` and `except` where you try to get the name, if it doesn't work reassign the object such that you can get the name.

Comment: Without more context, it's impossible to say what the appropriate behaviour would be - what should the user be doing with `None`? If you've documented that the function could `return None`, why can't you expect them to handle that case? If you return some dummy object on which they *can* call `getName` (which can write to the log as you require), what should happen *after* they've done so - presumably the normal program flow can't continue indefinitely assuming that the returned object wasn't a dummy?

Comment: I think people generally use decorators to enforce things for a comparatively non-hell-bent-to-foil-your-api user.

Comment: I understand that the python idiom is don't force your users, I'm trying to educate the average user, not the hacker user. So that if a user does not check if the object is none, and tries to access an object method they will get an error in the log or exception. This way when the users are educated I can remove in production the code which forces the check.

Comment: As far as C++: the goal is not to have these problems in a production envuironment, hence in development environment a "crash" is a good thing so it's not the NULL value which worries me but not testing for NULL, and getting a good value. (in dev time I can assume that values will be good usually hence if the dev does not test for NULL he might not encounter the NULLs, so I force him to test for NULL by crashing if he doesn't test for it an get a good object)

Comment: Malik Brahimi: I want to minimize production code problems, hence in development time I want to have the test for "not None" adding a try catch is something the user needs to do as well, if I can't force them to test for None, how will I force them to add a try/catch? Obviously I don't want a try catch which is larger than the scope in which the users code runs, or I miss my base intention here.

Comment: You're thinking statically.  Python is a dynamic language, and it's usually not a good idea to try to force structure on client code.  Who knows what the code will do with your object?  Maybe it'll get pickled, byte-by-byte compared to the `None` object by some non-Python code, and then unpickled somewhere else.  You don't want to prevent that, do you?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to replace automated tests by runtime warnings that say something like "hey, looks like some automated tests would fail if you had any". Have you looked into static analysis tools that you might be able to run on the users' code?

Comment: I'd recommend [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot force the use of `if x is not None` because you cannot override the behavior of `id()`. The `is` operator internally compares the ids of the two objects being compared, and you have no way of controlling that behavior.

However, you *can* force the use of `if x != None` or `if not x == None`by overriding the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) methods of your class, respectively.

This is *not* good practice, however. As @Kevin has noted in the comments, `is` is the preferred operator to use when comparing to `None`.

What I would do is write clear and organized documentation for this API, and then clearly warn users that the instantiation could fail and return `None`. Then, gently nudge users towards good practices by providing an example with the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function or an example with the `is not None` check.

Comment: Especially since `is None` is the [preferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) way to check for `None`.

Comment: I know that is None, is the preferred way to check, that is why I am trying to hook it. The API in question is an internal API, not external so I pretty much have control about how people will use it, just not about the quality of their code.

Comment: @MaxShifrin That's the first time you've mentioned it being an internal API.

Comment: @MaxShifrin The internal-ness or external-ness of your API is irrelevant. If you're able to tell your users that they have to use `is not None`, then you're also able to tell them *why* they should use it and what may happen if they don't. It's better to enlighten than to enforce. All of this will probably be in the documentation unless you want to personally mentor every single user of your API.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was already said, you can't override `is` behavior.

To do what you want, basically you can create a surrogate object that has a `getName()` function.  To let the user check if the function failed, you can have the object evaluate to `False`.  (This is a standard practice and I think this is better than making the object equal to `None` with the `__eq__` operator).  To do this, you can override override `__nonzero__()` having it return `False`.

Example:

```
class GetObjectFailed(object):
    def __nonzero__():
         return False
    def getName():
         return "An error has occurred" # You could specify a specific error message here...

x = getObject(...)
print x # prints "An error has occurred"
if x:
    # This is the recommended way of doing things
    # Do something with the object
    x.proccess()
if x is not None:
    # This will never work
    x.proccess()
if x != None:
    # This is possible but not recommended
    x.proccess()
```